# Using CEFSharp to edit <textarea>

Tags: javascript, c#, html, winforms, cefsharp

I am able to edit a regular textbox within an iFrame in CefSharp like so:

```
Browser1.GetBrowser().GetFrame("iFrame1").ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("document.getElementById('ElementID').value=" + '\'' + "1234" + '\'');
```

However, because a textarea doesn't have a value:

```
<iframe id="iFrame1" name="iFrame1">
    <textarea name="txtareaname" id="txtareaname1">sometexthere</textarea>
</iframe>
```

I am unable to execute a similar line of code to edit the text in the textarea:

```
textarea.Browser1.GetBrowser().GetFrame("iFrame1").ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("document.getElementById('txtareaname1').value=" + '\'' + "1234" + '\'');
```

I have also tried:

```
textarea.Browser1.GetBrowser().GetFrame("iFrame1").ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("document.getElementById('txtareaname1').innertext=" + '\'' + "1234" + '\'');
```

How do I adjust my code to edit this textarea?

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging for how to debug javascript. In general get your code working in `Chrome` then use it in `CefSharp`. You should change the tags of this question to include `javascript` and `html`, remove some of the not so relevant ones like `c#` and `winforms`.

Comment: Try https://jsfiddle.net/9tw12vmj/

Comment: @amaitland Hey - I really appreciate your reponse. I've actually already tried what is in your jfiddle. It still won't change - I'm at a complete loss :(. I've read through the wiki over the weekend, and still can't figure it out.

Comment: You can debug using DevTools see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging

Comment: Setting value should be fine. For example [`document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = "Fifth Avenue, New York City";`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_textarea_value2) - Make sure you are using correct id.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yeah - I thought so too, but it's not working - it just refuses to change. I am 100% certain that I am using the correct id. Could it be because it's in an iFrame?

Comment: Maybe you are running the code when the document is not ready yet.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I wish :( - but I'm physically waiting until the document has completely loaded. I'm able to edit all other fields in the page inside the same exact iFrame - just not this textarea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **OP**: However, because a `textarea` doesn't have a value I am unable to
>   execute a similar line of code to edit the text in the `textarea`.

The assumption is wrong, setting `value` attribute works fine for `teaxtarea`.

You should just make sure the document, including the iframe has been loaded and you have selected the correct iframe using correct name and then you have selected the correct textarea using correct id.

**Example**

Here is a minimal complete verifiable example which shows how you can find the `iframe` and set the value of a `textarea` inside the `iframe`.

To make the example independent from externals sources and make verification easier, instead of initializing iframe using its `src` attribute, I've initialized `iframe` using script.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnLoad(e);
    var content = new HtmlString(@"
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <iframe id=""iFrame1"" name=""iFrame1"" src=""about:blank""></iframe>
    <script>
        var doc = document.getElementById('iFrame1').contentWindow.document;
        doc.open();
        doc.write('<html><head><title></title></head><body>' + 
        'Address:<br>' +
        '<textarea id=""myTextarea"">342 Alvin RoadDucksburg</textarea>' +
        '</body></html>');
        doc.close();
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
    ");
    var browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(content)
    { Dock = DockStyle.None, Size = new Size(400, 200), Location = new Point(8, 42) };
    Controls.Add(browser);

    var button = new Button() { Text = "Click Me", Location = new Point(8, 8) };
    Controls.Add(button);
    button.Click += (obj, args) => {
        browser.GetBrowser().GetFrame("iFrame1")
            .ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("document.getElementById('myTextarea').value=" +
            "'Fifth Avenue, New York City'");
    };
}
```

Comment: It works! I guess I just needed the semicolons. On another note, is there a way to get Fifth Avenue and New York City on different lines?

Comment: Yes there is, `"'Fifth Avenue, \\nNew York City'"`.